# Is Account new OR specific field is changed?

Tags: process-builder

I am trying to write check method in process builder. But couldn't manage run process builder smoothly. This is what I want and what I tried

if (Account is new OR **AA_field** changed) AND (B_field is null))

Then run the action

```
OR(ISNEW(), ISCHANGED([Account].A_field), AND(ISNULL([Account].B_field)))
```

But I am doing it wrongly. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you wrote it, you are performing OR operation all the conditions. Instead, it should be like this:

```
AND(OR(ISNEW(), ISCHANGED([Account].A_field)), ISNULL([Account].B_field))
```

Representing this in multiple lines for clarity would be like this:

```
AND(
    OR(
        ISNEW(), 
        ISCHANGED([Account].A_field)
    ), 
    ISNULL([Account].B_field)
)
```

Also, looks like you might be using this formula in process builder because you chose `Formula evaluates to true` under `Criteria for Executing Actions*`. Instead, you can

1. Choose `Conditions are met` under `Criteria for Executing Actions*`
2. Specify the conditions
3. Choose/ Specify `Conditions *` & `Logic *` as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: this explains a lot thank you!